# Resetting offset for partition after (Re-)joining group

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, apache-kafka-streams, akka-kafka

here is the problem: due to some issues (probably network) our application losing connection with 3 of 5 our Kafka brokers:

```
Error sending fetch request (sessionId=2108009367, epoch=INITIAL) to node 4: 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1169924518, epoch=INITIAL) to node 1: 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1156529071, epoch=INITIAL) to node 5: 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
```

After this there is a big amount of similar logs about unavailable group coordinator:

```
Group coordinator <host>:9093 (id: 2147483642 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
Discovered group coordinator <host>:9093 (id: 2147483642 rack: null)
```

And so on and so on hundreds of times, but then consumer group rejoins successfully, but loses previously commited offset:

```
Revoking previously assigned partitions [<topic>-0, <topic>-1, <topic>-2]
(Re-)joining group
Successfully joined group with generation 1
Setting newly assigned partitions: <topic>-0, <topic>-1, <topic>-2
Found no committed offset for partition <topic>-0
Found no committed offset for partition <topic>-1
Found no committed offset for partition <topic>-2
Resetting offset for partition <topic>-0 to offset 3812363 (first within retention period).
```

But problem is that this offset **3812363** is not correct offset, this is the earliest, so after rebalancing and rejoining consumer group we get incorrect offset. Because of that or application reprocesses big amount of data within retention period which is really bad :(

Maybe somebody faced similar issues? I will be happy to share any information like logs, configs that you will find useful, just let me know!

**UPD**
Consumer code:

```
  def receive: Receive = {
case job: Job =>
  Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))
    .collect { case msg@JsonTx(tx) => (msg, tx) }
    .mapAsync(streamParallelism) { case (msg, tx) =>
      currencyNormalizer.normalize(tx).map { msg -> _ }
    }
    .mapAsync(streamParallelism) { case (kafkaMsg, message) =>
      //build tx and persist to DB
    }
    .map { case (kafkaMsg, message) =>
      //send to other topic
      ProducerMessage.Message(new ProducerRecord[String, String](configService.topic, message.toString()), kafkaMsg.committableOffset)
    }
    .via(Producer.flow(producerSettings))
    .map(_.message.passThrough)
    .batch(max = 100, first => CommittableOffsetBatch.empty.updated(first)) { (batch, elem) =>
      batch.updated(elem)
    }
    .mapAsync(streamParallelism) { msg =>
      commitOffsets(msg)
    }
    .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
  ()
```

}

```
private def commitOffsets(x: ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffsetBatch): Future[akka.Done] = {
    retry
      .Backoff(max = maxRetries, delay = offsetRetryDelay, base = offsetBackoffBase)
      .apply {
        Try(x.commitScaladsl()) match {
          case Success(value) => value
          case Failure(e) =>
            logger.warn("Failed to commit offsets. Retrying...", e)
            throw e
        }
      }(retry.Success[akka.Done] {_ => true}, ec)
  }
```

**UPD 2**
Dependency we use, I don't see and Alpakka dependencies in the code

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-kafka" % Versions.akkaKafka
```

Comment: Based on the tags I will assume that you are using Alpakka (edit your post detailing dependencies if I'm wrong. I suggest the following articles. [Alpakka - consumer](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html), [Alpakka - error handling](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/errorhandling.html). The second one details how to address issues with Kafka and offset reset. Sharing details about how you are handling offset and failures will help

Comment: Are you ever committing offsets manually or automatically? Otherwise, auto.offset.reset=earliest will send you the beginning of the topic each time

Comment: We committing offsets manually using batches. I updated question with consumer code and dependencies

Comment: Akka Stream Kafka == Alpakka ;)

Comment: This sounds to me like Kafka lost your consumer offsets.  Are the broker nodes 1, 4, and 5 healthy?  If not, there's a chance that the consumer offsets (stored in the `__consumer-offsets` topic) are on those three nodes, in which case trying to recover them is what you need to do.

Comment: And yes, I've seen something like this before: in my case, compaction silently stopped working on the brokers which meant that the `__consumer-offsets` topic wasn't being compacted, which eventually meant that Kafka couldn't figure out the correct offset.

Comment: Thanks! But I still not sure what I need to do, this nodes are healthy 100%, they maybe not available for some time, but after some time it automatically reconnects and everything working fine except offsets are lost.